# JPA/Hibernate cascade remove not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item extends Unit
{
    // @Id is in superclass

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ItemRelation> lowerItemRelations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ItemRelation> higherItemRelations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // this too is in superclass
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("date")
    protected Set<UnitRegistration> registrations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_RELATION",
    indexes = @Index(columnList = "PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID", unique = true))
public class ItemRelation extends AbstractEntity
{
    // @Id is in superclass

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Item parent;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Item child;

    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL")
    private int quantity = 1;

    ...
}
```

Now I just want to perform a simple `em.remove(item)`, but Hibernate does not issues the related `DELETE` statements for `lowerItemRelations`/`higherItemRelations`.

Conversely, for all other fields annotated with `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "...", cascade = CascadeType.ALL/REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true)` it issues the statements.

Here is a little MySQL log snippet:

```
2016-09-28T08:47:52.090453Z   13 Query  update UNIT set CODE='CE13000003167', ... where ID=132241 and version=1
2016-09-28T08:47:52.094971Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT_ACTION where PARENT_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.134999Z   13 Query  update AUTHORIZATION set UNIT_ID=null where UNIT_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.158014Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT_DOCUMENT where PARENT_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.248074Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT_PRODUCT where UNIT_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.315641Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT_PROJECT where UNIT_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.586008Z   13 Query  delete from ITEM_ALTERNATIVE where ITEM_ID=132241
2016-09-28T08:47:52.853350Z   13 Query  delete from AUTHORIZATION where ID=714491
2016-09-28T08:47:52.910835Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT_REGISTRATION where ID=173505
2016-09-28T08:47:52.980887Z   13 Query  delete from UNIT where ID=132241 and version=1
2016-09-28T08:47:53.133290Z   13 Query  rollback
```

As you can see, there's no line for deleting from `ITEM_RELATION`, and I'm expecting something like:

```
0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000Z   13 Query  delete from ITEM_RELATION where PARENT_ID=132241
0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000Z   13 Query  delete from ITEM_RELATION where CHILD_ID=132241
```

Obviously the transaction is rolled back, because of:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`edea2`.`item_relation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_RELATION_CHILD_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`CHILD_ID`) REFERENCES `unit` (`ID`))
```

Another strange thing is that Hibernate performs an (unnecessary?) `UPDATE` as first statement.

However,

- is this different behavior related to the fact that `lowerItemRelations`/`higherItemRelations` references the same entity type (although on different fields/columns AND different rows)?
- Is this a bug or there's a reason for such behavior?

What I tried:

- initialize the collections
- initialize and clear the collections (to trigger orphanRemoval)
- `em.remove()` each collection element prior to `em.remove(item)`

without success.

The only working way I found till now is to issue:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaDelete<ItemRelation> delete = builder.createCriteriaDelete(ItemRelation.class);
Root<ItemRelation> rel = delete.from(ItemRelation.class);
delete.where(builder.or(
    builder.equal(rel.get(ItemRelation_.parent), managedItem),
    builder.equal(rel.get(ItemRelation_.child), managedItem)));

em.flush();

em.remove(managedItem);
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.2.Final on Wildfly 10.1.0.Final

Thanks

---

As requested here is where `em.remove()` is called:

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class PersistenceService implements Serializable
{       
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    ...

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public <T> void delete(T entity)
    {
        T managed;

        if(!em.contains(entity))
        {
            Class<T> entityClass = EntityUtils.getClass(entity);
            Object entityId = EntityUtils.getIdentifier(entity);

            managed = em.find(entityClass, entityId);
        }
        else
        { 
            managed = entity;
        }

        em.remove(managed);

        // em.flush(); // just for debugging
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you apend snipped of code where `em.remove(item)` fails ?

Comment: Please see update. It fails on tx commit (or em.flush() when uncommented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's a bug.

I found this behavior is coupled with lazy initialization of both collections, so I submitted the issue [HHH-11144](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11144) and produced a simple test case (also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mmariotti/HHH-11144)).

In short, this happens when

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

tx.begin();

Item item = em.createQuery("select x from Item x where x.code = 'first'", Item.class).getSingleResult();

Set<ItemRelation> lowerItemRelations = item.getLowerItemRelations();
Hibernate.initialize(lowerItemRelations);

// initializing 'higherItemRelations' prevents orphanRemoval to work on 'lowerItemRelations'
Set<ItemRelation> higherItemRelations = item.getHigherItemRelations();
Hibernate.initialize(higherItemRelations);

lowerItemRelations.clear();

tx.commit();
em.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that `Unit` is refferencing something else and is not exclusive to your root - `ItemRelation` in this case, thus cannot be deleted.

Your mapping suggest that `Unit` can have multiple `ItemRelations` so this is most probably the issue here. You would have to "break" the relation first by removing mutual references on both sides (or at least on entity that helds FK, or any of them if join table is used)

Comment: I don't understand your answer... Of course Unit is referencing other entities (like UnitRegistrations that I put in example), in fact the goal is to delete all of them at once (where cascaded). The mapping between Item <-> ItemRelation is completely expressed in the snippet (@OneToMany/@ManyToOne with @JoinColumn), you see there's no @JoinTable. Please, can you elaborate?

Comment: I know that action can cascade from top to bottom where it ends, but what you want is cascade process bounce back from the bottom to the top and start over again with N number of other related entities. IMHO `cascade` will not handle this, but i can be wrong.

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. I don't want to delete *related items*, I just want to delete the *managedItem* and all of its *lowerItemRelations* and *higherItemRelations* ItemRelation entities, which hold the two FKs to UNIT table - as you can see ItemRelation.parent and ItemRelation.child are not declaring the cascade attribute, so I'm not asking hibernate to delete the full graph, just the target entity and the immediate ItemRelation neighbours (where cascade is declared) :)